# Wordpress the_category() to php string

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the WordPress `the_category()` function to output as a string so I can use it as part of another variable.

This is the code I'm using, I'd like `$the_category` to output the HTML result of `the_category()`.

```
    function more_post_ajax(){

    $ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 3;
    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;

    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'paged'    => $page,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    $out = '';

    if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
    
        $the_permalink = get_the_permalink();
        $the_post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( medium );
        $the_category = the_category();
        $the_title = get_the_title();
        $the_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    
    
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
            $thumbnail = '<div class="card-img-wrap"><a href="'.$the_permalink.'" title="'.$the_title.'" class="stretched-link"><img src="'.$the_post_thumbnail.'" class="card-img-top wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" /></a></div>';
        endif;
    
        $out .= '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                <article itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-3">'.$thumbnail.'
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="postcat text-muted text-center">'.$the_category.'</div>
                            <h4 class="posttitle text-center" itemprop="headline" title="'.$the_permalink.'" rel="bookmark"><a href="'.$the_permalink.'">'.$the_title.'</a></h4>
                            <div class="postexcerpt text-center mb-3">'.$the_excerpt.'</div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <div class="social-icons">
                                    <ul class="unstyled">
                                        <li class="social-facebook"><a href="//www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$the_permalink.'" title="Share to Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="social-twitter"><a href="//twitter.com/home?status='.$the_permalink.'" title="Share to Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="social-pinterest"><a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url='.$the_permalink.'" title="Share to Pinterest" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
';

    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die($out);
}
```

If possible, I'd like to do something similar for `the_post_thumbnail()`.

Comment: try with ```get_the_category()``` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Comment: `get_the_category()` returns an array - you have to either implode it to a list with a comma, or choose a value with an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_the_category() which will provide list to a php variable.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

the_category() will directly display/print the category from specific post.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category/

Comment: This answer doesn't fully explain the question, and only the output from the_category would be a string.